# SD card has CURRENT Read-only State : Yes

Tags: sd-card, read-only

```
DISKPART> attributes disk
Current Read-only State : Yes
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

DISKPART> attributes disk set readonly

Disk attributes set successfully.

DISKPART> attributes disk
Current Read-only State : Yes
Read-only  : Yes
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

DISKPART> attributes disk clear readonly

Disk attributes cleared successfully.

DISKPART> attributes disk
Current Read-only State : Yes
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

DISKPART>
```

How do I set the "Current Read-only State" to "No"?
The regedit "writeProtect" method doesn't work. Re-formatting doesn't work. No physical switch on a microSD.

Card is read by card reader of the same brand.

What happened prior to this situation:
Card was working top-notch. Then I didn't use it for a couple of months, so it was just laying around in a suitable environment. Now I plugged it in and it is set to read-only.

P.S.: It is a Transcend card, not SanDisk.

Comment: I specifically pointed out that all these questions didn't help.

Comment: The card itself is protecting the data, it is damaged and will not allow writes to the card, they do this so at least you can salvage data from the card as writes to it may make all the data corrupted or inaccessible.

Comment: You missed also running `attributes volume clear readonly`